# Checking whether an Anonymous Type equals to a specified type or not

Tags: c#

```
class test<type>
{
    public test()
    {

    }

    public bool byteTest()
    {
        return new byte().Equals(new type()); // Error at new type()
    }   
}
```

I want to check whether an anonymous type is a specified type. (like byte)

Why I want to do this something similar like this is I want to limit the anonymous type. Like I just want to declare the anonymous type as a byte or integer.

Comment: a.gettype().tostring() == b.gettype().tostring() ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to see if a type parameter (`type`) is instantiated as a specific type (`byte`). If so try the following

```
public bool byteTest() {
  return typeof(byte) == typeof(type);
}
```

The name `type` here refers to a generic type parameter.  An anonymous type in C# refers to a value created via an anonymous type expression.  Like so

```
var x = new { Name = "john", Age = 42 };
```

Note: To avoid confusion with the type `Type` i would choose a more standard generic argument name like `T`, `TValue`, etc ...

Comment: thank you ! I'm using different AnonymousType name too. It was just an example. I think this'll work

Comment: ahh I always get confused about these definitions :D Yes It's a generic type parameter :)

Answer (score 1):

The `is` keyword in C# is meant specifically for this purpose:

```
object something = "I am a banana.";
if (something is string)
{
    // This will execute, because something is a string.
}
```

Note that the following test is false, even though `null` is a valid value for a string.

```
object something = null;
if (something is string)
{
    // This will not execute.
}
```